# font-face not working in firefox

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time of why my font-face is not working in firefox, it worked perfectly fine in chrome, here's the css that I have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArvoRegular';
    src: url('http://cf.shopious.com/fonts/arvo-fontfacekit/arvo-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://cf.shopious.com/fonts/arvo-fontfacekit/arvo-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://cf.shopious.com/fonts/arvo-fontfacekit/arvo-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://cf.shopious.com/fonts/arvo-fontfacekit/arvo-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://cf.shopious.com/fonts/arvo-fontfacekit/arvo-regular-webfont.svg#arvoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.arvo-regular {
font-family: 'ArvoRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Here's the [site](http://dev.shopious.com). Based on my understanding that this is the correct way to do it

Comment: Your font is in Google Fonts: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Arvo . Use it.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor doesn't really answer the question, I have my own font hosted in own CDN server

Comment: Alright, I assume you don't want to use Google's CDN. Any error / warning in Firebug's Network & Console ?

Comment: Have you checked the compatibility with your browser on MDN? Here is the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing I see wrong with your CSS. I'm betting it's a **cross-domain issue** (I've run into that in the past). Take a look at this article: http://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts.